# (web2py) add extra fields auth_user that reference another field

Tags: authentication, web2py, login-control

I am using Web2py and I would like to add extra fields in the auth_user. some of these fields are reference to other table. for example:

auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [
    Field('country', 'reference countries')]

db.define_table(
    'countries',
    Field('name'),
    format = '%(name)s'
)

but I receive this issue:
cannot resolve reference countries in auth_user definition

can any one help me what should I do? how can I link auth_user table with another table???

All the Best

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure your db.define_table  is created before your  the auth tables
like this :

```
  db.define_table('bank',
  Field('name'),
  format = '%(name)s')

     auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = 
      [Field('bank', 'reference bank',
      label = T('Bank'),
      notnull = True,
      required = True,
      requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.bank.id, '%(name)s') ),
```

]

```
   auth.define_tables(username = True, signature = True)

  custom_auth_table = db[auth.settings.table_user_name]

 auth.settings.table_user = custom_auth_table
```

Comment: What if I just want to add a filed (type int), that references table bank, but it is not a drop down. So every time a user registers he/she adds new record to table bank even if one with the same name already exists?